# What kind of tracks is this?

Tags: pcb, trace

I'm trying to know What kind of tracks is this?(What do you call this kind of tracks?)

[image: figure1]

I mean those soldered tracks. I guess this kind of trick could help to increase the thickness of lines and thus you can draw more current through these lines(tracks).

Am I right?

How much it can help to draw more current? is there any approach to calculate it?

Comment: Related: http://www.eevblog.com/2012/07/21/eevblog-317-pcb-tinning-myth-busting/ TLDR: It does not help with resistance much, but it might positively affect power dissipation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the solder is there to increase the thickness and lower the resistance/increase the current capacity of the track.

Dave from EEVBlog has an [episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9q5vwCESEQ) on this topic. He found that you get 15% - 50% decrease in the resistance of the trace depending on the thickness of the solder coating.